# How to collect RSS feed from Twitter Search?

Tags: twitter, rss, feed

to the point. I need collect Rss Feed from Twitter Search. Usually it can appear like this:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=KEYWORD
```

I Have try googling for 3 days and the result is same. It can appear with this script

```
Hashtag search: http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=%23YourSearch

User mention search: http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=%40UserName

To a User: http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=to%3AUserName

From a User: http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=from%3AUserName
```

But.. It can run anymore. it have an error like this

```
<errors>
   <error code="68">
The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.
   </error>
</errors>
```

seems twitter has change the API.

Can anyone help me for this problem? I need the Feed for built the twitter bot.

is there any other way to get the feed from twitter?

Im Very Appreciated your Advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter does not support RSS anymore.

Answer (score 0):

But still you can generate a twitter RSS feed with third party application.

https://queryfeed.net

It does exactly this however, the website does have a bit of downntime i observed in last 2 days.